# How to make a combined search box with different URLs?

Tags: javascript, search, web-search

I want to create a search box that will combine search URLs and combine the results.

So if I wanted to Use Google Web Search and Google Image Search, I would use www.google.com/search?q= and www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=905&q= and then I would have:

Search: https://www.google.com/search?q=cats & https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=905&q=cats

Cats Website Link
Description

Picture of a cat

(sorted by relevancy)

Is this even possible? I know that it has been done with dogpile, but all I want to do is combine a couple different Google products so I can search my documents, my images, etc.

Note: I have no experience with Javascript, PHP, Ajax, or search boxes.

Thanks, Ian.

Comment: wow, well, for a lack of experience, you're jumping in the deep end.  Second, it's very possible, and even easy using a little jQuery-Ajax magic on your javascript and maybe a rc call on php, but again, you're really jumping in the deep end for a first time proj

Comment: This isn't really designed for teaching people how to do things - this is more for helping you along the way when you run into specific issues. And yes - its possible. :P

Comment: OK, thanks. I had no idea if this was an easy or a hard project. It sounded like it would be easy because you can easily make a search for just one search URL, so I thought it wouldn't be too hard with two. Now that I think of it though, getting all the results to stay inline with each other, as well as sorting them and formatting, would be pretty hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be achievable with the [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html), but you will need to learn a programming language.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking, but I really don't need it so much that I am going to learn an entire programming language. HTML an CSS are enough. :D